# Bisecting k-means clustering algorithm explanation

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, k-means

I was required to write a bisecting k-means algorithm, but I didnt understand the algorithm.
I know k-means algorithm.

Can you explain the algorithm, but not in [academic language](http://www.siam.org/meetings/sdm01/pdf/sdm01_05.pdf)

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The idea is iteratively splitting your cloud of points in 2 parts. In other words, you build a random binary tree where each splitting (a node with two children) corresponds to splitting the points of your cloud in 2.

You begin with a cloud of points.

- Compute its centroid (barycenter) w
- Select a point at random cL among the points of the cloud
- Construct the point cR as the symmetric point of cL when compared to w (the segment cL->w is the same as w->cR)
- Separate the points of your cloud in two, the ones closest to cR belong to a subcloud R, and the ones closest to cL belongs to the subcloud L
- Reiterate for the subclouds R and L

Notes :

You can discard the random points once you've used them. However, keep the centroids of all the subcoulds.

Stop when your subclouds contain exactly one point.

If you want k clusters, just take k centroids such that they contain all the points of the initial cloud. You can do much more elaborate stuff if you want (minimizing variance of the clouds, etc...) Suppose you want 4 clusters (a power of two for convenience) Then you only need to cut you cloud in two, and then cut each subclouds in two. If you want 8 clusters, then cut again these subclouds once in two. And again for 16 clusters.

If you want K clusters with K not a power of 2 (let's say 24) then look at the closest inferior power of two. It's 16. You still lack 8 clusters. Each "level-16-cluster" is the centroid of a "level-16-subcloud". What you'll do is take 8 "level-16-clusters" (at random for example) and replace them each with the two "child" "level-32-clusters". (These two child "level-32-clusters" correspond to two "level-32-subclouds" that add up to the parent "level-16-subcloud")

Comment: Thanks for your answer, much clearer now. But I have 2 thing I didnt understand - "Select a point at random cL among the points of the cloud" - mean that I need to select a random vector?
The second thing - I didnt understood what I need to do for K clusters?

Comment: Well, you've got a cloud of points that you want to clusterize, right? Selecting a point in the cloud means... selecting a point in the cloud =) I don't exactly get what you mean by random vector... Choose among the points of the cloud, not at random in the whole space. I've updated my post for the K clusters

Comment: I guess vector mean point =] But what if my random selection isnt good and cause uneven split clusters? I though on doing: each thing I'll choose the cluster with the biggest SSE - what you think?

Comment: I think that the algorithm is appears quite... bad. But in fact, it's not really! I think there's a million way to improve it, and yes, your idea is surely good even if I don't know what's SSE (what's SSE btw?). But I think the idea is that this is fast, and you can build lots of bisecting k-means, the same way you would make random forests (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest) (If you read the link, you should know that bisecting k-means is really really really like a decision tree)

Comment: Yeah its sum of squared errors, and thanks. I guess I'll ask the professor if he meant just splitting - like you said or something smarter. EDIT: one thing - after I select a random point and its symmetric point and split the cluster into two clusters- theres no optimization on that clusters? Like in regular k-means theres always optimization until theres isnt movement of the points between the clusters (or the movement is less then 1% ... )

Comment: Before you ask your professor, you should look at the article you gave. On page 3 is the algorithm for bissecting k-menas. And it's... **really simple**. That's way I said there are a trillion ways of improving it. But, as described, the algorithm is simple, and I guess there might be good reasons for that (computational cost). But I totally understand why you'd want to check a few things to avoid choosing very bad clusters, I have the same feeling!